# Output selected array in SugarCRM email

Tags: arrays, arraylist, sugarcrm

I created a form with a multi-select field where three values are going to be stored as an array in SugarCRM. Now, I want to call the variable when I'm sending out a mail through the process email template.

Normally, you can call the values stored in the field with `{::Leads::field_c::}`

SugarCRM then gives back all selected values by separating with comma `value1, value2, value3`

I would like to be able to display only one variable of the array, normally I would have used `$field_c['value2']` or `$field_c[1]`

However, SugarCRM does not take any of my code…already tried different variations…

Is it possible that Sugar converts the array coming from the contact form and simply stores it as a text field using the commas as separators? Or why can't I select a specific variable in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do that in process email template , it is predefined .

If you want to put data like you want , then you have to create a email template and write a code to trigger that email, in that code you can get specific value of the dropdown.

[Custom Email](https://johndopenotes.wordpress.com/2013/03/26/sugarcrm-send-email-with-attachment-using-sugarphpmailer-class/)